# .aac extension audio files are played on IE

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, .htaccess, audio

In my local Wordpress running in XAMPP, I noticed that the post with an audio file attached with `.aac` extension, the audio works fine in Chrome and it does not work in IE11 where I get "Download File". This message "Download File" comes from mediaelementjs because IE does not seem to be supporting `audio/aac` files with extension `.aac`.

I read several references in internet where some links suggest IE supports `.aac` in HTML5 and some suggest it does not.

I added the following in `.htaccess` and this did not help either.
AddType audio/aac  .aac
AddType audio/mp4  .mp4 .m4a
AddType audio/mpeg .mp1 .mp2 .mp3 .mpg .mpeg
AddType audio/ogg  .oga .ogg
AddType audio/wav  .wav
AddType audio/webm .webm

Anyone of you faced such issue and I would appreciate any help to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: The server serving the .aac file has to provide the proper mime type as well.

Comment: Chrome does not have this problem, so it must be getting the mime type. Why would server does not provide the mime type for IE (and Firefox)?

Comment: I don't know what your server does, I'm just saying that IE requires the mime type to be set.

Comment: much AV support is provided by the OS/codec, perhaps you are missing a codec.